# How to specify the linking type in CMake?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

In my CMake script I need to specify for different library, that my project is linked against, different types of linking for gcc. It is well-known to use `-Wl,-Bstatic` and `-Wl,-Bdynamic` options for such kind of mixing. But is it possible to specify this somehow in cmake script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use a couple of macros that adjust CMake's preferred search order on Linux/MacOSX to switch between dynamically and statically linked libraries

```
macro( prefer_static )
    if( NOT WIN32 )
        list( REMOVE_ITEM CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES   ".a" )
        list( INSERT      CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES 0 ".a" )
    endif()
endmacro()

macro( prefer_dynamic )
    if( NOT WIN32 )
        list( REMOVE_ITEM CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a" )
        list( APPEND      CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a" )
    endif()
endmacro()
```

we then call the appropriate `prefer_static()` or `prefer_dynamic()` routine prior to calling `find_library(...)` or `find_package(...)`. This has the advantage of "falling back" on a shared library when a static library is not available, or vice-versa.

This won't work for Windows builds because you always link to a `.lib` file with Visual Studio and (AFAIK) there's no a straightforward way to determine if it's a static or dynamic library.

Comment: you can enhance the macro to find the library in user define path also! Nice logic.

Answer (score 0):

In CMake `find_library` can be used for this purpose.

`find_library(VAR libMyLib.a)` OR `SET(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a") find_library(VAR MyLib)`